# Search for words into an arbitrary string. Which method is fast sql query or binary search?

Tags: sql, ruby, search, permutation, binary-search

So if I have the following string:

orig_string = 'adklsdn**the**asnien**words**nsaldkng**are**lskndl**in**asldkn**here**'

and I iterate through it like so:

```
orig_string.length.times do |index1|   
    orig_string[index1..orig_string.length].length.times do |index2|   
        puts orig_string[index2..orig_string.length]   
        unless orig_string[index1..index2].length == 0 then puts orig_string[index1..index2] end  
    end  
end
```

to get every possible combination of the string with order preserved. I am trying to pull as many english words from this string as possible by referencing a dictionary of ~5,000 words. Eventually I plan to iterate over many strings so performance is key, which is why I am deferring to my peers.

Would it be quicker to load the dictionary into memory and binary search through it, or load it into an sqlite3 db and run a query for each permutation?

Also, is there a better way to get all permutations of the original string with order preserved?

Thanks!!

Comment: "binary search?" you have to scan the string to find words. binary search works on ordered data...

Comment: right, so the each piece of the original string will be searched for in an ordered dictionary either in an in-memory array or sqlite3 db. I just am curious which would be the right choice, as well as if there is a more efficient way to find all the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

### **Find all substrings inside a string**:

I think the following implementation for break string into words is more clear, ruby-like and little bit faster:

```
orig_string     = 'adklsdntheasnienwordsnsaldkngarelskndlinasldknhere'
orig_string_len = orig_string.length

orig_string_len.downto(1) do |len|
  (orig_string_len - len).downto(0) do |index|
    puts orig_string.slice(index, len)
  end
end
```

### **Search for valid words**:

I guess binary search is faster than SQL queries, since data is already in memory and is just a function call.

SQL will parse the query and will do many other calculation before return the value.

There is other aspects to considerate, like sqlite3 is a C implementation, maybe it is faster than ruby binary search for a large set.

If this algorithm will be heavy use, I suggest you to benchmark both approaches.

Ruby has a pretty easy lib for this stuff http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/benchmark/Benchmark, which comes with the Ruby Standard Lib.

Comment: wow that is a much better implementation, thanks! I think I will try and benchmark both, see which turns out better, and report back.